# pattern to release objects in a managed language

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dispose, managed

In a complex application (involving inversion of control and quite some classes) it is hardly possible to know when a certain object won't be referenced anylonger.

First Question: Suggests the statement above that there is a design flaw in such an application, since there is a pattern saying: "In all OO programming it is about objects using other types of objects to ease up implementation. However: For any object created there should be some owner that will take care of its lifetime."

I assume it is save to state that traditional unmanaged OO programming works like stated above: Some owner will eventually free / release the used object.

However the benefit of a managed language is that in principle you don't have to care about lifetime management anymore. As long an object is referenced anyhow (event-handler...) and from anywhere (maybe not the "owner") it lives and should live, since it is still in use.

I really like that idea and that you don't have to think in terms of owner relationships. However at some point in a program it might get obvious that you want to get rid of an object (or at least mute it in a way as it wouldn't be there).

**IStoppable**: a suggestion of a design pattern
There could be an interface like "IStoppable", with a "Stop()" method and an "Stopped" event, so that any other object using it can remove their references onto the object. (Therefore would need to unplug their OnStopped event handler within the event handler if that is possible). As a result the object is no longer needed and will get collected.

Maybe it is naive but what i like to believe about that idea is that there wouldn't be an undefined state of the object. Even if some other object missed to unregister itself on OnStopped it will just stay alive and can still get called. Nothing got broken just by removing most references onto it.

I think this pattern can be viewed as an anarchistic app design, since

- it is based on the idea that ANY other object can manage the lifetime of an IStoppable
- there is no need for an owner
- it would be considered as OK to leave the decision of unregistering from an IStoppable to those using it
- you don't need to dispose, destroy or throw away - you just stop and let live (let GC do the dirty part)

**IDisposable**: from scatch and just to check a related pattern:
The disposable pattern suggests that you should still think and work like in unmanaged OO programming: Dispose an object that you don't need anylonger.

- **using** is your friend in a method (very comfortable!)
- an own IDisposable implementation is your friend otherwise.
- after using it / calling Dispose **you shouldn't call it anylonger: undefined behaviour.**
- implementation and resource centric: it is not so much about when and why, but more about the details of reclaiming resources

So again: In an application where i don't have in mind if anything else but an "owner" is pointing to an object, it is hard to ensure that noone will reference and call it anylonger.

I read of a "Dispose" event in the Component class of .NET. Is there a design pattern around it?

Why would i want to think in terms of Disposables? Why should i? 
In a managed world...

Thanks!
Sebastian

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't like the idea of `IStoppable`, as defined above.  You're saying you want any object to manage the lifetime of the object - however, a defined lifecycle really suggests ownership - allowing multiple objects to manage the lifetime of a single object is going to cause issues in the long

`IDisposable` is, however, a well defined pattern in the .NET world.  I wrote an [entire series on implementing IDisposable](http://reedcopsey.com/series/idisposable/) which is a decent introduction to it's usage.  However, it's purpose is for handling resource which have an *unmanaged* component - when you have a managed object that refers to a native resource, it's often desirable to have explicit control of the lifetime of that resource.  `IDisposable` is a defined pattern for handling that situation.

That being said, a proper implementation of `IDisposable` will still clean up your resources if you fail to call `Dispose()`.  The downside is that the resource will be cleaned up during the object's finalization, which could occur at any arbitrary point after the object is no longer used.  This can be very bad for quite a few reasons - especially if you're using native resources that are limited in nature.  By not disposing of the resource immediately, you can run out of resources before the GC runs on the object, especially if there isn't a lot of memory pressure in the system.

Comment: agreed.  sebastian, it might be helpful if you could give a more concrete example of where you dont think the existing model works for you

Comment: @Reed aside from the add/remove ref idea (which is really bad) the idea of Start()/Stop() seems like a reinvention of Open()/Close().

Comment: i try completely rephrase to understand you:
"You need a defined lifecycle. For any object created there should be some owner that will take care of its lifetime. That way you will end up with a hierarchical object graph where each object has an owner that manages the lifetime of its childs."

correct?

"the owner is not necessarily the creator of the object. With dependency injection e.g. object creation is managed for you. However you always need to define an owner that manages the lifetime of the newly created object" (?)

is that the basic truth and where is the explaining pattern for it?

Comment: AND: "you should always know which other objects will reference your child so that they can release the object when you dispose it." (?)

after rephrasing please tell me why!
what is the Dispose event of the .NET component for if not for exactly the same thing: unreference the disposed object. don't call it anylonger! @Conrad: what is so bad about OnStopped? And yes. It is a reeinvention of Open/Close. Just call it Close then.

What is good about a disposed object? How should i ensure that it dosen't get called anymore? 
A managed GC is so radical but it seems to not be used. Why?

Comment: @Sebastian: Typically, you don't need a defined lifecycle.  But, in the rare cases where you DO need a defined lifecycle, that object should have a known owner.  I personally, in a situation like this, would not use DI unless absolutely necessary - rather, I'd use DI to provide the factory to the object which will "own" the resulting resource.

Comment: @Sebastian: The problem with not having a defined ownership of a resource is that it becomes very difficult from a maintainability standpoint to manage that resource effectively.  The end result tends to be resource leakage or mis-management.

Comment: @Sebastian: Close() typically is handled by Dispose(), btw.  Failing to Close() an object in .NET should not [when implemented properly] be a problem, as the managed GC will handle this.  When the object is no longer referenced, the finalizer will cleanup the resource.  The problem is more of a "when" than an "if" - the resource will get cleaned, but you have no control over when it'll get cleaned.  Again, I'd recommend reading my articles on IDisposable, as I go into when and why it's used.  ...

Comment: @Sebastian: If you really need a non-owned object with a native resource, you can leave it undisposed, and let the GC take care of it.  Task/Task<T> are often handled this way - they're disposable, but they're nature really prevents ownership in many cases, so it's nearly impossible to correctly call Dispose() on them.  Typically, it's better to just let the GC handle their resource cleanup.

Comment: @Sebastian: I don't have a problem with OnStopped or Even Stop/Start. "What is good about a disposed object?" Other process can now use the managed resource it was using (like a file, connection string, handle) "How should i ensure that it dosen't get called anymore." You can't you throw an ObjectDisposedException. Callers will have to learn to inspect status and reopen, not call close until they mean in, or when there is no open to create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok first I would point out a few things I find uncomfortable about your IStoppable suggestion.

1. IStoppable raises event Stopped, consumers must know about this and release references.  This is a bit complex at best, problematic at worst.  Consumers must know where every reference is in order to remove/reset the reference.
2. You claim "... Nothing got broken just by removing most references onto it.".  That entirely depends on the object implementing IStoppable and it's uses.  Say, for example, my IStoppable object is an object cache.  Now I forget about or ignore the event and suddenly I'm using a different object cache as the rest of the world... maybe that is ok, maybe not.
3. Events are a horrible way to provide behavior like this due to the fact that exceptions prove difficult to handle.  What does it mean when the third out 10 event handlers throws an exception in the IStoppable.Stopped event?

I think what your trying to express is an object that may be 'owned' by many things and can be forcefully released by one?  In this case you might consider using a reference counter pattern, more like old-school COM.  That of course has issues as well, but they are less of a problem in a managed world.

The issue with a reference counter around an object is that you come back to the idea of an invalid/uninitialized object.  One possible way to solve this is to provide the reference counter with a valid 'default' instance (or a factory delegate) to use when all references have been release and someone still wants an instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding of modern OO languages; in particular scope and garbage collection.

The lifetime of the objects are very much controlled by their scope.  Whether the scope is limited to a using clause, a method, or even the appdomain.

Although you don't necessarily "care" about the lifetime of the object, the compiler does and will set it aside for garbage collection as soon as it goes out of scope.

You can speed up that process by purposely telling the garbage collector to run now, but that's usually a pointless exercise as the compiler will optimize the code to do so at the most opportune time anyway.

If you are talking about objects in multi-threaded applications, these already expose mechanisms to stop their execution or otherwise kill them on demand.

Which leaves us with unmanaged resources.  For those, the wrapper should implement IDisposable.  I'll skip talking about it as Reed Copsey has already covered that ground nicely.

Answer (score 0):

While there are times a Disposed event (like the one used by Windows Forms) can be useful, events do add a fair bit of overhead.  In cases where an object will keep all the IDisposables it ever owns until it's disposed (a common situation) it may be better to keep a List(Of IDisposable) and have a private function "T RegDisp<T>(T obj) where T:IDisposable" which will add an object to the disposables list and return it.  Instead of setting a field to SomeDisposable, set it to RegDisp(SomeDisposable).  Note that in VB, provided all constructor calls are wrapped in factory methods, it's possible to safely use RegDisp() within field initializers, but that cannot be done in C#.

Incidentally, if an IDisposable's constructor accepts an IDisposable as a parameter, it may often be helpful to have it accept a Boolean indicating whether or not ownership of that object will be transferred.  If a possibly-owned IDisposable will be exposed in a mutable property (e.g. PictureBox.Image) the property itself should be read-only, with a setter method that accepts an ownership flag.  Calling the set method when the object owns the old object should Dispose the old object before setting the new one.  Using that approach will eliminate much of the need for a Disposed event.